# How to use * to include even dotfiles

Tags: command-line

Currently I have example code which looks like

```
git clone repo/ ./tmp
mv ./tmp/* .
```

When using `*` it doesn't include dotfiles

How can I include dotfiles by using `*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short version is that you can't.  File globbing (`*`) doesn't include dot-files, so you'd need to modify your shell's code to support that behavior (or refuse to support the existing behavior, more likely), which you're *probably* not going to do and you definitely don't want to do, because of the two dot-files in every directory, `.` and `..`, that'll get you into trouble.

Instead, you'll want to move the files separately, something like:

```sh
mv ./tmp/* .
mv ./tmp/.??* .
```

The second line globs dot-files that aren't just the current or parent directory.

If you (for whatever reason) *need* this to happen in one command or have more sophisticated criteria to work with, you might want to investigate `find`'s `-exec` argument, which lets you run a command against pretty much any file list generated by time, contents, name, or a variety of other characteristics.